# `-ddump-cmm` not working in a Stack Script

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am using Stack to write a script and would like to see GHC's C-- output.

I have the following at the top of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script
   --resolver lts-9.9
   --install-ghc
   --package doctest
   --package QuickCheck
   --
   -ddump-cmm
-}
```

The output from `-ddump-simpl` gets printed to the terminal, but not so with `-ddump-cmm`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try `--ghc-options="-ddump-cmm"`?

Comment: I had tried that! Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

If you run your script manually with the `-v` flag, using:

```
$ stack -v script --resolver lts-9.9 --install-ghc
   --package doctest --package QuickCheck -- -ddump-cmm Script.hs
```

you can see that the Script is actually run with `runghc`, like so:

```
runghc -hide-all-packages -packageQuickCheck -packagebase 
    -packagedoctest -ddump-cmm Script.hs
```

It turns out that `runghc` invokes GHC using something equivalent to:

```
ghc -ignore-dot-ghci -x hs -hide-all-packages -packageQuickCheck
   -packagebase -packagedoctest -ddump-cmm
   -e ":set prog Script.hs" -e ":main" Script.hs
```

If you try invoking GHC manually this way, you'll find that the `-ddump-simpl` flag generates output, but the `-ddump-cmm` doesn't.  It seems that the `-e ":main"` argument switchs GHC from "compile in advance" mode to just-in-time compiling.  The "simpl" is still generated, but the CMM is presumably generated on an as-needed basis, so the `-ddump-cmm` flag is ignored.

The `stack script` command has `--compile` flag, but it's not clear how to pass options to GHC when this flag is in force.  (It's really an accident that you can pass compiler flags to `runghc` when not using `--compile`, I think.)

I think your best bet is to just manually compile the script with GHC.